# Laptop Screen Brightness

Tags: laptop, display, brightness

What controls the brightness levels in a laptop? Is it the BIOS?

Is it possible to modify the brightness levels to have a custom brightness at each level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Brightness Controls on Integrated Display Panels:](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/f/7/af7777e5-7dcd-4800-8a0a-b18336565f5b/Brightness.docx)

> In Windows operating systems,
> brightness controls are implemented in
> the operating system-supplied monitor
> driver, *Monitor.sys*. The monitor
> driver implements a Windows Management
> Instrumentation (WMI) interface to let
> applications—such as the operating
> system’s brightness slider—interact
> with the brightness level.
>
> The
> monitor driver registers with the
> operating system device power policy
> so that brightness levels respond to
> changes in power policy. The monitor
> driver registers for Advanced
> Configuration and Power Interface
> (ACPI) notifications to process
> ACPI-based brightness shortcut keys.
>
> An OEM can implement brightness
> control by using function shortcut
> keys such as **Fn-F6** or **Fn-F7**.

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks Mehper, this is useful. Do you have any idea where to start modifying a monitor driver?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry but I have no experience in that. Maybe you can ask another question on how to modify a monitor driver?

Answer (score 0):

most laptops will have settings for brightness up and down that you can access with a function key (usually labeled as fn) in conjunction with some of the F keys (for example the F7 (down), and F8 (up) keys on my laptop or any HP for that matter).

Comment: Hi MaQleod, those are the settings I want to modify. I want the brightness settings to be linear, and i want to know how to change the brighness at each level.