# Laptop screen at 40% brightness when first turned on

Tags: brightness, laptop-display, windows-10-v1511

I have several HP ZBook 17 G3's that my company just purchased. They are all imaged with an up-to-date Windows 10 image, and the first thing I do after imaging them is run HP Support Assistant to ensure the drivers are all updated as well (they are thankfully...the Win 10 images is updated regularly).

We are experiencing an issue with the display being dim when the end-user first starts the laptop in the morning. There is video, its just very dark. When I look at Display Settings on an affected machine, the Brightness slider shows it is at 100% Brightness, but when I check the actual brightness levels from an elevated command prompt with `wmic /namespace:\\ROOT\WMI path WmiMonitorBrightness get CurrentBrightness /format:list`, it shows that the brightness level is only 40%.

I have checked the power plan settings based on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/203389/laptop-screen-brightness), and they are the same as the other 357 laptops in the building, but just to be sure, I disabled any power management settings and set the power options to High Performance.

Which driver(s) should I be checking?

Comment: Have you checked the [Battery Saver Settings](https://i.sli.mg/rBqQsc.png)?

Comment: I just checked with a user that has the issue and one who doesn't. Lower screen brightness is checked on both. Users unplug their laptops and store them in their locker at the end of their shifts. It is possible that some laptops are not shutting down and thus the battery is less than 20%. I will have to check that next time. I did some checking on my laptop, and when I first undocked, it went to 40% brightness, but every thing I fiddles with after that only dropped it to 70%. It does seem to indicate it is power related though.

Comment: Turning off Battery Saver seems to have done the trick. No issue for the last 2 days.